# How to add label in navgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I use jqgrid.I  want use label in navgrid and dynamic change label text.
I can add button by navButtonAdd.
how to add label in navgrid?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `caption` property of jqGrid navGrid. As given in the [Wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator) you can see that for existing navGrid buttons you can use the property `addCaption/editCaption` in case of Edit and `caption` in case of others to set the label.
As

```
caption: "Delete",
```

Since this is a string value you can directly assign a variable dynamically to set the label

Answer (score 0):

If you *really need* to modify the text of the buttons added by `inlineNav` or `navGrid` you have to do this manually because jqGrid has no simplified function for this.

First of all you can use Developer Tools of Internet Explorer (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to start), Firebug or other tools to examine the navigator buttons. You will see something like

[image]

The `id` of every button are constructed from the id of the grid and some button specific suffix. For example the "Edit" button added by `inlineNav` is `"list_iledit"` where `"list"` is the id of the grid and the suffix `"_iledit"`has the Edit button. To change the texts later you can use the code like

```js
var $div = $("#" + grid[0].id + "_iledit>.ui-pg-div");
var $icon = $div.find(">span.ui-icon");

$div.text("edit"); // new text of the button
$div.append($icon);
$div.parent().attr("title", "my custom edit tooltip"); // new tooltip
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But I don't need to modify the text of the buttons.I want Add Label for display mytext like caption in titlebar  of jqgrid

Comment: @ZSH: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Is it not easier to save our time and append the code which you use? What you mean under "Add Label"? Do you used `navGrid` [options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#parameters) `edittext`, `addtext` and so on or `caption` option of `navButtonAdd`?

Comment: I put image in my question.

Comment: @ZSH: What is "MY Text"? Do you used [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) method or not? What is your code? You wrote in your question about "dynamic changing label text". You wrote that you used `navButtonAdd`. Which options you used?

Comment: I can add button by  navButtonAdd.Now I want have label like "View 1-10 of 11" for display userName+description

Comment: @ZSH: Sorry, but you use permanently wrong terminology. "Label" is wrong in the case. Do you examined first [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager) of jqGrid?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
.navGrid('#pager_list_1', {
    //other codes
    }).navButtonAdd('#yourpagerId', {
            caption: "Del",
            url: delUrl,
            buttonicon: "ui-icon-trash",
            onClickButton: function (response) {}
            }
```